# asp:imagebutton hover effect css

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the buttons below working so that the buttond do what they have to, but i would like to add a CSS so that they can hover is there any method of doing this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="pageID"
                      DataSourceID="SQLData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     PageSize="1" Width="100%" Height="500px" 
                    GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="pageID" HeaderText="pageID" InsertVisible="False" 
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="pageID" ShowHeader="False" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="sectionID" HeaderText="sectionID" 
                            SortExpression="sectionID" Visible="False" ShowHeader="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="pageNo" HeaderText="pageNo" SortExpression="pageNo" 
                            Visible="False" ShowHeader="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="pageTitle" HeaderText="pageTitle" 
                            SortExpression="pageTitle" Visible="False" ShowHeader="False" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pageContent" SortExpression="pageContent" 
                            ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-CssClass="pagecontent">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pageContent") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPageContent" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pageContent") %>' CssClass="pageContent"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious"  
                        NextPageImageUrl="~/images/navButtonNext.png" NextPageText="Next Page"  
                        PreviousPageImageUrl="~/images/navButtonPrevious.png"  PreviousPageText="Previous Page" LastPageImageUrl="images/navButtonNext.png" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="navPager" HorizontalAlign="Right"  />
                    <PagerTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="navBack" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/navigation/grey_bttn_back.jpg"  CssClass="sec" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" ClientIDMode="Static" AlternateText="Back" ToolTip="Back" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="navHome" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/navigation/grey_bttn_up.jpg"  CommandName="gotoHome" ClientIDMode="Static" AlternateText="Home" ToolTip="Home" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="navFwd" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/navigation/grey_bttn_fwd.jpg" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" ClientIDMode="Static" AlternateText="Fwd" ToolTip="Fwd" />
                    </PagerTemplate>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to do this. Bind your image buttons in mouse move event and add a class something like "hover" to the image button if mouse is hovered on it. Use your Css to style if the image button contains class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("navBack").onmousemove=function(){
this.setAttribute('class', 'hover');
document.getElementById("navHome").className="";
document.getElementById("navFwd").className="";
}

document.getElementById("navHome").onmousemove=function(){
this.setAttribute('class', 'hover');
document.getElementById("navBack").className="";
document.getElementById("navFwd").className="";
}

document.getElementById("navFwd").onmousemove=function(){
this.setAttribute('class', 'hover');
document.getElementById("navHome").className="";
document.getElementById("navBack").className="";
}

}
</script>
```

Note: Don't forget to remove class name from image buttons if mouse is not hovered on them. Use css effects you want for the class "hover".

Comment: Use window.onload instead of document.onload, I'll edit my code

Comment: thanks for the helo using fire bug i can see the class being added onto the page but it doesnt seem to still work thank you for all the help.